# Set Ad-Hoc View, to filter according to logged in language

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

When a user creates a Ad-Hoc report, it will bring back data from All languages (Yes I know the user can manually filter by language)

I need to change the jasper code so that the Ad-Hoc view will automatically only show data according to logged in language

So if you are logged in, in English and create a Ad-Hoc view, it will only bring back English data

Note: The database is setup so that I can just use

```
Where language_id = 3
-- 3 = English (this will change depending on logged in language)
```

and it will show the correct data for that language

So what I am asking is, how can I change the Jasper-server code so that it automatically filters by language (AKA only show data of the logged in language) for the Ad-Hoc Views

Comment: Note: using Jasper-server 5.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged this issue with Jaspersoft they say it is not possible at the moment.

They have filed a enhancement request and hopefully we will see this enhancement in a new release of Jaspersoft

Comment: Hello, did you get any further with this? (Old post I know!)